# MariaDB galera cluster, add node without interruption

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I would like to setup a Galera Cluster with 3 servers.
But i have a question who can be a problem :

- How can i add a new IP in wsrep_cluster_address parameter to allow this new server to be sync in the cluster without interruption ? (restarting mariadb)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In general you don't need to do this. When cluster is running it [discovers all other nodes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/#adding-another-node-to-a-cluster) dynamically from any node it connects first, so you specify just any joined node(s) in this setting:

> The new node only needs to connect to one of the existing cluster
> nodes. Once it connects to one of the existing cluster nodes, it will
> be able to see all of the nodes in the cluster.

However, it is recommended you specify all nodes in this variable. It is supported even to specify all nodes including itself, so you just specify the same string into all node's configuration. But, you don't need to restart node. This setting is needed *in case* you'll restart it, for it to be able to join a running cluster, but when cluster is assembled all nodes know all others anyway. So in general you build a cluster, and then update `wsrep_cluster_address` in the config files, but you don't need to restart nodes afterwards.

However, if ISTs are configured properly, node restart is relatively fast, because it only tranfers missing writesets from active nodes (so "incremental" state transfer), not the complete dataset as it would in case of SST. So you may restart node without major disruption. Your application should be able to cope with this small disruption, for example, reconnect to any other alive node (or else Galera cluster is useless).

This means, you might well join 2nd and 3rd nodes into the cluster, then update configuration on 1st node and restart it; during its downtime there will be a quorum 2 of 3 notes, and when it is ready it will rejoin a cluster using its `wsrep_cluster_address` variable. I'll even suggest to do this, just to know what happens when you restart a node.

Also note, Galera's `wsrep_*` configuration directives are system variables. Many of them can be [set interactively](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#setting-server-system-variables) without restart. The `wsrep_cluster_address` can be changed at runtime:

```
SET GLOBAL wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://node1,node2,node3";
```

this may cause the node [reconnection](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_cluster_address).

> The variable can be changed at runtime in some configurations, and
> will result in the node closing the connection to any current cluster,
> and connecting to the new address.

So it is not much different, to set it like this, or to simply restart a node after updating it's config file.

Comment: I've used galera with haproxy. For example we used xinetd script to verify DB availability (updating a specific record in the DB) and this allowed me to stop xinetd and tell haproxy to stop routing new connections to the node.

Answer (score -1):

(I don't know the exact steps for adding the 4th node.)

When announcing a new node to a Galera cluster, the following happens, assuming Galera is installed, but no data exists in it yet.

1. An existing node is picked as the "donor".
2. SST is performed to copy the entire state of the data from the donor to the new node.
3. The new node is declared to be online.

Step 2 takes an amount of time based on dataset size.  And it bogs down the donor due to I/O.  There are several ways that copy can occur; see the configuration settings.